# How can I log a stack trace when I throw an exception? Is the logger PSR-3 compatible?

Tags: debugging, 10

I'm trying to log a stacktrace when I throw an exception [as suggested here](http://bestpractices.thecodingmachine.com/php/error_handling.html#always-log-exceptions-with-the-stacktrace).

I tried this:

```
  catch (\Exception $e) {
    \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->error($e->getMessage(), [ 'exception' => $e]);
  }
```

However, the stacktrace doesn't get logged; I only see the error message.  How can I log the stacktrace as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Drupal 9 because the Drupal 9 logger is not PSR-3 compatible.

However, Drupal 10 alpha [already supports PSR-3 logging](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3272447), so this feature will be available shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for Drupal 8 and 9:

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
  \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->error("<pre>$e</pre>");
}
```

This works because [`Exception::__toString`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.tostring.php) includes the stack trace. `<pre>` ensures that line breaks are shown properly in your browser when looking at the error logs.